# How to set mock nuxt asyncData in jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I am using Nuxt.js and want to test my page which uses `asyncData` with Jest. I have a factory function to set up my wrapper, but it basically returns a `shallowMount`.

#### Expected

When clicking a button I want the function to behave differently depending on the query parameter. When running the test I want to mock this by setting it directly when creating the wrapper (Similar to setting propsData). E.g. `const wrapper = factory({ propsData: { myQueryParam: 'some-value' } });`

#### Result

However trying to set propsData still returns undefined: `console.log(wrapper.vm.myQueryParam); // undefined` while I would expect it to be `'some-value'`

#### Question

Is there a different approach on how I can test this function that relies on query parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `asyncData` is called before Vue is initialised, it means `shallowMount` doesn't work right out of the box.

### Example:

#### page:

```js
<template>
    <div>Your template.</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    async asyncData({
      params,
      error,
      $axios
    }) {
        await $axios.get("something")
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### test:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
describe('NewsletterConfirm', () => {
  const axiosGetMock = jest.fn()
  const axiosPostMock = jest.fn()
  var getInitialised = async function (thumbprint) {
    if (thumbprint == undefined) throw "thumbprint not provided"

    let NewsletterConfirm = require('./_thumbprint').default
    if (!NewsletterConfirm.asyncData) {
      return shallowMount(NewsletterConfirm);
    }

    let originalData = {}
    if (NewsletterConfirm.data != null) {
      originalData = NewsletterConfirm.data()
    }
    const asyncData = await NewsletterConfirm.asyncData({
      params: {
        thumbprint
      },
      error: jest.fn(),
      $axios: {
        get: axiosGetMock,
        post: axiosPostMock
      }
    })
    NewsletterConfirm.data = function () {
      return {
        ...originalData,
        ...asyncData
      }
    }

    return shallowMount(NewsletterConfirm)
  }
  it('calls axios', async () => {
    let result = await getInitialised("thumbprint")
    expect(axiosGetMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  });
});
```

Credits to [VladDubrovskis for his comment](https://github.com/nuxt/docs/issues/1600#issuecomment-535994612): [in this nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/docs/issues/1600)

Comment: On nuxt 2.15 i needed to use NewsletterConfirm.`options`.data to make it work.